# What do you call the act of submitting to someone?

Tags: word-request

I am wondering if there's a word you can use for animals like dogs and wolves. Is there some kind of gestures or action that imply submitting oneself to a stronger individual?

Here's an example sentence:

> The other wolves * before the alpha wolf after he showed how much more
>   powerful it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you want is [**grovel**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grovel):

> **2 a** : to lie or creep with the body prostrate in token of subservience or abasement
>   // *groveled* at the feet of the king
>   **2 b** : to abase oneself
>   // would not *grovel* for political advantage

Note that when dogs grovel, they bare their throats to the dominant member as an act of submission. (The physical action is a little different than how a human would grovel, but the idea of being prostrate is the same.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest *cower*: "to crouch down in fear".  But it has many close [synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cower) with slightly different connotations, that might also fit.

If it is meant to convey respect or humility instead of just fear, you could consider [genuflect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genuflection), but that isn't something wolves would do.